# problemas com autofocus em input personalizado

Tags: jquery, html

galera criei um input personalizado, ele funciona 100% o problema e que o autofocus não esta funcionando.

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Segue o código

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/56pafcne/)

Comment: aqui está funcionando, chrome v48.0.2564.109 windows

Comment: o problema e que ele so funciona no google chrome, acabei de notar isso

Comment: Compatibilidade: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp

Comment: estranho, eu ja tinha conferido a compatibilidade dele. Porém acho que o jQuery que estou usando fez o auto focus bugar. No safrari ele sobe a animação, porem so é possível digitar no input se eu clicar nele

Comment: @FelipeAssunção esta compatibilidade esta errada, estou usando a ultima versão do firefox 44.02 e não esta funcionando o autofocus...

Comment: então aqui continua sem funcionar em alguns navegadores

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema com o `autofocus="autofocus"`

Comment: no safari continua sem funcionar

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=autofocus

Comment: desculpa minha ignorância, mas não entendi. Poderia ser mais claro?

Comment: Nesse site você pode acompanhar quais navegadores suportam a propriedade.

Comment: a entendi, vlw pela ajuda :)